# How do I integrate WordPress blogs with my Grails application?

Tags: wordpress, grails

I had my static site with which [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) blogs were integrated. Now I have made a [Grails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29) application with which I want to integrate those WordPress blogs.

I had put the WordPress folder copied from my previous site to the web-app folder of my Grails application. But I am not able to access the WordPress folder, as when I hit URL - http://localhost:8080/myApplicaiton/wordpress/, it shows this error:

> Error 500: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Also, in my `urlMappings.groovy` one of the mappings I need is

```
"/$generalPageURL"(controller:'myConroller', action:'myAction')
```

And if I put in the above mapping, all requests for WordPress goes to `myAction` of `myController`. Is there any way out to still reach the WordPress folder defined inside web-app folder with the above mapping?

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly, but your WordPress blog need PHP in order to run. You maybe better off using an HTTP server like Apache with PHP on the front and use either a [mod_proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_proxy) or [mod_jk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_jk) type of configuration to connect the two applications (Grails and WordPress) together. That way your users can see http://www.yoursite.com/wordpress and http://www.yoursite.com/grailssite, with the HTTP requests being handled by Apache and then have it pass the Grails part off to [Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29)/[GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) or whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do this in reverse order config apache to redirect to php site not the grails to redirect to apache server.